# how to insert javascript code in html for tab blocking

Tags: javascript

How do I insert JavaScript code in html for tab blocking?

For example I want my web page to run an alert which will block the browser tab. 
I have tried

`<script>alert("hello");</script>`

Comment: `var url=window.prompt('Enter URL');
window.location.href=url;`

Comment: Rayon. Thanks but this script don't block browser tab.

Comment: Please define _block browser tab_...

Comment: "Block browser tab" This function looks like a winlocker. When user click on "close tab"  he's can't close. I don't know how to explain otherwise.

Comment: @craft1k, actually `window.prompt` will block the tab, same as `alert`. You won't be able to close the tab, without closing the prompt dialog before. Just try it yourself. Press `F12` copy paste the code above into console, press `enter`, try to close the tab.